# Display sibling pages including current page in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a page structure like this:

- Food

  - Cheese
  - Fruit
  - Meat
  - Sweets
- Music

  - Rock
  - Dance
  - Folk

When on a child page, I want to a menu that shows the siblings, including the current page. For example, if I am on the 'Fruit' page I want to see:
**Cheese**  Fruit  **Meat**  **Sweets**

'Fruit' should not have a link because it is the current page.

I've tried this, but it doesn't include the current page:

```
<?php
  wp_list_pages(array(
 'child_of' => $post->post_parent,
 'exclude' => $post->ID,
 'depth' => 1
  ));
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code have exclude argument, just remove  `'exclude' => $post->ID`,so you can see your current page too...

```
<?php
  wp_list_pages(array(
 'child_of' => $post->post_parent,
 'depth' => 1
  ));
?>
```

and to make unclickeble please use below style

```
<style type="text/css">
    .current_page_item a{
   pointer-events: none;
   cursor: default;
   color: #000;
}
</style>
```

So final code is

```
<style type="text/css">
    .current_page_item a{
   pointer-events: none;
   cursor: default;
   color: #000;
}
</style>

<?php
  wp_list_pages(array(
 'child_of' => $post->post_parent,
 'depth' => 1
  ));
?>
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you! I added this to exclude the list title `'title_li' => ''`

Comment: You are welcome :) Please up vote this if usefull :)

Comment: Sorry, I tried, but don't have enough reputation :(

Answer (score 0):

Here is the logic you need to do. First get the post parent ID:

```
$post_parent_id = wp_get_post_parent_id( $post_ID );
```

Then get the children of the parent page :

```
$my_wp_query = new WP_Query();
$all_wp_pages = $my_wp_query->query(array('post_type' => 'page', 'posts_per_page' => '-1' , 'post__in' => array($post_parent_id)));

$children = get_page_children( $post_parent_id, $all_wp_pages );

echo '<pre>' . print_r( $children, true ) . '</pre>';
```